# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS bash: sudo: command not found

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sudo, apt-get

I am new to Linux terminal, now I tried to use sudo, apt-get, whereis etc., commands in linux it returns an error  bash: sudo: command not found

my command

```
 $sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Error is

```
 bash: sudo: command not found.
```

Please let me know what could be the issue here, thank you in advance

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/ instead.

Answer (score 30):

Try to login with su

```
$ su -
```

and install sudo

```
# apt-get install sudo
```

Comment: I have the same problem when I try to do 'su' my authentication does not work. Any ideas ?

Comment: yup, I was missing it completely, I had to 'apt-get install sudo' as root and then from my account was able to use sudo

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it isn't installed? Open your package manager and install the sudo package.

Also, try to use full path (if you have it installed)

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

if that command work then include `/usr/bin/` in your env variable PATH in `~/.bashrc`

```
echo "export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

hopefully works ..